# Getting value of super class from extended Gesturelistner class

Tags: java, android

I have an arraylist (wl) in my main activity class. It is being populated in the onCreate. I have verified that it is getting populated.

There is also a geturelistner variable. The gesturelistener class extends my main activity class. When I access arraylist(wl) from gesturelistner class it always returns empty.
Code as follows:

CLASS FC.JAVA

```
public class FC extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    ArrayList<W> wl = new ArrayList<W>();
    GestureDetectorCompat gDetector= new GestureDetectorCompat(this,new GestureListener());
    ...

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {...
    wl.addAll(dbw.getalphaall("A",level));    
    Log.d("WL LEN MAIN",wl.size()+"");
    ...
    }

    View.OnTouchListener gListener = new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if (gDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
                return true;   
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

CLASS GestureListener.JAVA

```
class GestureListener extends FC implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener, OnGestureListener
{    
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) 
{   ...
    Log.d("WL LEN GL", super.wl.size()+"");
    ...
    return false;
}
```

When I run my code

WL LEN MAIN returns 386

WL LEN GL returns 0

LOG CAT ERROR:

```
09-29 08:57:44.694: E/InputEventReceiver(2766): Exception dispatching input event.
09-29 08:57:44.694: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2766): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
09-29 08:57:44.764: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2766): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
```

Comment: Do you call `super.onCreate` in the `onCreate` of `GestureListener`? Otherwise, the list will never be filled.

Comment: There is no onCreate inside GestureListener. I realize that i can directly access wl i.e. by using wl.size() instead of super.wl.size(). But, the ouput remians same.